# jQuery - select divs with IDs that contain a certain string AND are part of a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

New to JS and jQuery, designing a game as an exercise.

I'm trying to select divs whose IDs contain a certain string AND have a certain class.

I know how to select a class:

```
$(".myClass")
```

and I know how to select for IDs that include a certain string:

```
$("[id*=" + certainString + "]")
```

But I do not know how to combine the two to get this:

```
$( elements of class ".myClass" that also have id that contains certainString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the selectors right next to each other (without a space in between) to select elements which have a certain class and *also* have an `id` matching the constraints:

```js
const certainString = 'foo';
const fooMyClasses = $(".myClass[id*=" + certainString + "]");
console.log(fooMyClasses.length);
console.log(fooMyClasses[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass">
</div>
<div class="myClass" id="foo123">
</div>
```